# Creating a deployment in Redhat Openshift using a specific USER id

Tags: docker, openshift

Redhat Openshift autumatically creates a range of user ids that can be used in a given namespace, e.g.

```
$ oc describe namespace xyz-123
Name:         xyz-123
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  xx.com/accountID: id-testcluster-account
              xx.com/type: System
              openshift.io/sa.scc.mcs: s0:c25,c20
              openshift.io/sa.scc.supplemental-groups: 1000640000/10000
              openshift.io/sa.scc.uid-range: 1000640000/10000
```

Here is the problem:

While creating docker image, I am setting USER id in Dockerfile:

```
USER 1001121001:1001121001
```

I am specifying runAsUser in Helm charts to deploy this image:

```
runAsUser : 1001121001
```

When I try to create the deployment, the deployment fails.  Because the user ID 1001121001 does not fall in the range above i.e. [1000640000, 1000640000+10000].

The deployment error:

```
$ oc get deployment abc-123 -n xyz-123 -o yaml
....
....
    message: 'pods "abc-123-7f8fc74765-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any security context constraint: [spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 1000321001: must be in the ranges: [1000660000, 1000669999]]'
....
....
```

Tried options - 1:

Using anyuid works as described here : https://www.openshift.com/blog/a-guide-to-openshift-and-uids
But the document says:
"Upon closer inspection of the “anyuid” SCC, it is clear that any user and any group can be used by the Pod launched by a ServiceAccount with access to the “anyuid” SCC. The “RunAsAny” strategy is effectively skipping the default OpenShift restrictions and authorization allowing the Pod to choose any ID."

Hence, I dont want to use this anyuid optiuon.

Tried option-2:
After creating a namespace get the range allowed for that namespace and select an id (say 1000660000) from that range and use that while deploying by setting that id for runAsUser: 1000660000.

All files/folders in the docker image will have the ownership/permissions set to USER 1001121001 and the container started with the id 1000660000 and hence there are issues running the container due to read/write/execute permissions.
To overcome this I need to give o+rwx permissions for all the files, which is risky.

Is there any other way to specify a USER in Dockerfile and use the same USER id during deployment in Redhat Openshift?

```
$ oc version
Client Version: 4.6.9
Server Version: 4.6.9
Kubernetes Version: v1.19.0+7070803
```

Solution:
The suggestion from Ritesh worked.
Created the namespace specifying the UID range and covering the specific USER ID.  Then created the deployment in this namespace:

Created a namespace with predefined user id range (covering the specific USER id 1001121001) before deploying into the namespace.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: xyz-123
  annotations:
      annotations:
    openshift.io/sa.scc.mcs: 's0:c26,c5'
    openshift.io/sa.scc.supplemental-groups: 1001120001/10000
    openshift.io/sa.scc.uid-range: 1001120001/10000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating namespace while doing deployment or before then can use following option. Using this you can use `runAsUser : 1001121001` (or any other user)
define the yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: dspx-dummy-runtimeid
  annotations:
    openshift.io/sa.scc.mcs: <>
    openshift.io/sa.scc.supplemental-groups: <>
    openshift.io/sa.scc.uid-range: <>
```

Use `kubectl apply -f <namespace.yaml>` or `oc apply -f <namespace.yaml>`.